# With specified username getting 'Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.' message when logging int

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I have installed the grails Spring-Security plugin:

```
plugins {
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
}
```

Then I used the grails s2-quickstart com.jane Person Role command to create the needed domain classes.

As I have my own User class I refactored the code to use my User class:

```
package com.jane

class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String email
    String name
    String password
    Boolean isAgreeTerms = false
    Date agreeTermsDt
    Boolean isActive = false
    Boolean isBlocked = false

    Date dateCreated
    Integer createdBy = 0
    Date lastUpdated
    Integer modifiedBy = 0

    static transients = [ 'springSecurityService' ]
    static hasMany = [ userProductTier: UserProductTier ]
    static mapping = {
        id          column: "userID"
        dateCreated column: 'createdDt'
        lastUpdated column: 'modifiedDT'
    }

    static constraints = {
        email       blank: false, email: true, unique: true, size: 5..100
        name        blank: false, size: 3..50
        password    blank: false
    }

    void beforeInsert() {
        if ( isAgreeTerms ) {
            agreeTermsDt = new Date()
        }
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
       }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

I then modified the config.groovy file to:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.jane.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.enabledPropertyName = 'isActive'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.accountExpiredPropertyName = 'isBlocked'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.accountLockedPropertyName = 'isBlocked'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.jane.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.jane.Role'
```

I can create users fine, verify they are in the database, have verified that encodePassword is called once. But every time I try to login I get the following error:

> Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and
>   password.

And here is the service method to create users:

```
User createTeamLeader( String name, String email, String password, Boolean isAgreeTerms, Integer productTierId ) {
    User user = new User( name: name, email: email, password: password, isAgreeTerms: isAgreeTerms, isActive: true)
    UserProductTier userProductTier = new UserProductTier( productTierId: productTierId )
    user.addToUserProductTier( userProductTier )
    user.save()
    UserRole.create( user, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'), true )
    UserRole.create( user, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_LEAD'), true )
    user
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the user and grant roles? It's usually helpful when seeing issues like this to crank up the logging - Spring Security logs a lot at the debug level. Add `debug 'org.springframework.security'` to the log4j block in Config.groovy

Comment: I added the function from my service above.

Comment: I did add the debug information. And, to an untrained eye, this seems the most relevant section:
Hibernate: select this_.userID ... from User this_ where (this_.email=?) limit ?
2013-12-08/21:57:18.259 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9]  DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
2013-12-08/21:57:18.259 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9]  DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
2013-12-08/21:57:18.264 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9]  DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/jane/login/authfail?login_error=1'

Comment: What should I be looking for in the logs to help debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often adding debug logging helps, since Spring Security logs a lot at the debug level:

```
log4j = {
   ...
   debug 'org.springframework.security'
}
```

In this case it didn't show the problem, so I added an event listener to see if there was information in the failure event:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "\nERROR auth failed for user $e.authentication.name: $e.exception.message\n"
}
```

That displayed this:

```
ERROR auth failed for user ernie@ss.com: No such property: authorities for class: com.jane.User
```

When you made changes in the class, you removed the `getAuthorities` method that was in the original version, and is used by the `UserDetailsService` to determine granted roles during authentication. Adding it back got things working:

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
   UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}
```

Comment: In my case after using the onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent which output: ERROR auth failed for user ernie@ss.com: No such property: passwordExpired

I added:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordExpiredPropertyName = 'isBlocked'

Based on the configuration options detailed here: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/domainClasses.html#personClass

Comment: @SamFarmer link is now dead

Comment: @mjones.udri updated link --> [link](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#personClass)