# TransactionManager error in grails app after installing spring-security-core

Tags: grails, spring-security

I've been struggling a bit with getting Spring Security Core integrated into my application and working properly. After some digging, I found a lot of good guidance, but have hit a wall. I'm basically at a place where my accounts exist, my roles exist, my passwords are being encoded properly, but logins are failing for every account.

I was following along with the debugging advice given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462446/with-specified-username-getting-sorry-we-were-not-able-to-find-a-user-with-tha) and it turned up an issue different than the one answered there, and which I haven't been able to find answers for when googling. This might be due to my newness with the framework.

I added this to my Config.groovy as Burt had suggested:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "\nERROR auth failed for user $e.authentication.name: $e.exception.message\n"
}
```

And tried again to log into my application. Again, I received the "Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password" error. When I looked at the console, having enabled extra logging via log4j also as directed in the above question, I found this:

```
ERROR auth failed for user bretw: No transactionManager bean configured
```

The full trace is here: http://pastebin.com/C2SkLgXZ

I certainly haven't configured any transaction management myself; is this something that's required by Spring Security Core, and if so, is there documentation for how to set it up that I'm just not seeing? I'm using MongoDB as my database, so I'm not using Hibernate.

I'm running Grails 2.3.4 and mongodb 1.3.0, with spring-security-core 2.0-RC2.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462446/with-specified-username-getting-sorry-we-were-not-able-to-find-a-user-with-tha): [With specified username getting 'Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.' message when logging int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462446/with-specified-username-getting-sorry-we-were-not-able-to-find-a-user-with-tha) ""

Comment: Has this been isolated to Spring Security?  Have you tested that GORM is working?  Can you do any data retrieval?  I'm asking this, because I had a similar error when using the GORM MongoDB plugin.  I ended ditching the plugin altogether though, so I never got around to debugging the problem.

Comment: GORM was working before, but stopped working when I added in the plugin. I'm switching back to my master and getting a fresh branch to try re-integrating this again. I found some directions from Burt at http://bit.ly/1yUetiq that look promising so I'm going to give those a second try from a known, good starting point.